# AngularJs Dynamic Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi This is my AngularJs One time loads pagination ... Can any one please tell me  how can i implement lazy loading with this (That is I need to call the service every time  for each page)

```
//get the list and injects to the template
        DWHDataExtract.list().then(function(response){

            DWHDataExtract.loaded = response.data;
            $scope.dwhDataExtractDetails = DWHDataExtract.loaded;
            $scope.stParams.reload();

        });
        // parameters declared inside the scope for row count and pagination view
        $scope.stParams = new ngTableParams({

                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 10 // count per page
            },
            {
                counts: [10, 25, 50, 100],
                total: $scope.dwhDataExtractDetails.length,

                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    //this criteria is for search filters
                    var searchOptions = params.filter();
                    var filteredList = searchOptions ? $filter('filter')($scope.dwhDataExtractDetails, searchOptions) : $scope.dwhDataExtractDetails;
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredList, params.orderBy()) : filteredList;

                    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                    if(params.total() < (params.page() -1) * params.count()){
                        // auto reset to first page if the current page is Out Of Bounds following a recent filter
                        params.page(1);
                    }

                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be put into a put into the controller so that it runs everytime a new controller is created.

angular.module('App')
.controller('controller', ["$scope", function($scope){

//PUT YOUR CODE HERE.
}]);